# How to get rid of "Does not have a default value" in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, timestamp

I am having an error:

```
doesnt have a default value (SQL: insert into `news` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-02-09 18:45:57, 2021-02-09 18:45:57))
```

I read, that this error appears when you try to insert a NULL value, but the weirdest part for me is, that despite the error, it still saves this data in DB(with correct created, updated fields).
Here is the code in controller:

```
public function addArticle(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    $news = new News;

    $news->insert([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'content' => $data['content'],
        'photo' => $data['photo'],
        'author' => 1,
        "created_at"=> now(),
        "updated_at"=> now(),
    ]);

    $news->save();

}
```

Comment: You don't "get rid of" that issue, you fix it. Set a default in the schema, or set a value when calling `insert()`. Either way.

Comment: You can set default value of column to NULL in database schema

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a new object in database by using the eloquent model "News". In the line `$news = new News;`you instantiate an object without passing parameters to the constructor. After that you try to insert that data. I guess the exception occurs on line 4.

Try something like this

```
$news = new \App\Models\News([
    'title' => $data['title'],
    'content' => $data['content'],
    'photo' => $data['photo'],
    'author' => 1,
    "created_at"=> now(),
    "updated_at"=> now(),
]);

$news->save();
```

or

```
$isCreated = \App\Models\News::create([
    'title' => $data['title'],
    'content' => $data['content'],
    'photo' => $data['photo'],
    'author' => 1,
    "created_at"=> now(),
    "updated_at"=> now(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addArticle(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    $news = new News;

    $news->insert([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'content' => $data['content'],
        'photo' => $data['photo'],
        'author' => 1,
        "created_at"=> now(),
        "updated_at"=> now(),
    ]);

    $news->save();

}
```

Looking at your code, i can find that you are saving data in two instances. Firstly you are using insert() method that is accepting the payload and inserting the data to you table. There is not exception in this step.

Exception is raised when you are calling `$news->save()` because save is trying to store the $news object which is not populated for attributes and hence is trying to save a blank object. This is throwing exception.

If you are using save , you just need to populate the attributes and rest all will be done by save. Saving eloquent object also helps you with created and updated set to now().

I will update this code as follow:

- Create fillable in News Model (if fields are correctly mapped)

  ```
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'photo', 'author'];
  ```
- would use mass assignment in addArticle.

  ```
   public function addArticle(Request $request)
   {
       $data = $request->only('title', 'content', 'photo', 'author);
       //update author if source of data is other than request payload
       $data['author'] = 1

       $news = News::create($data);        
       // return response as required. 
   }
  ```